# sendFile express return special chars

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to res.send a Json file however when i do that it keep returning a lot of special chars like following:

```
book����mark����8���8���`Q�����������eÇ¾Ju¼A����rs/ftP��������������Applications�����MAMP�����htdocs�������organization.json�����������$���0���@��������T÷Ó����������¬Ô0����������ëé0����������Ð
```

`

What am i doing wrong``

my code:

```
router.get('/beacy', function(req, res, next){

    res.set('content-type','application/json; charset=ansi')
    res.sendFile("/organization.json", { root : __dirname});


});
```

**json file**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Designmuseum Danmark",
        "shortName": "Designmuseum",
        "image": "http://designmuseum.dk/assets/62/page/hovedindgang.jpg?1297094752",
        "pin": "http://www.slu.edu/campusmap/images/pin.png",
        "logo": "http://designmuseum.dk/images/design-museum-danmark.png?1403008440",
        "locations": [
            {
                "longitude": 12.583886,
                "latitude": 55.679145
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Louisana",
        "shortName": "Louisana",
        "image": "http://whereisyvette.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/img_0641.jpg",
        "pin": "http://www.slu.edu/campusmap/images/pin.png",
        "logo": "http://www.e-flux.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/4deeb_nov22_louisiana_img.jpg?b8c429",
        "locations": [
            {
                "longitude": 12.538708,
                "latitude": 55.685163
            },
            {
                "longitude": 12.548171,
                "latitude": 55.694565
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you using the last version of express? which version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The file is sent correctly, you just need to send the right content-type to the browser to see the JSON file.

for example

```
res.set('content-type','application/json; charset=ansi')
```

or

```
res.set('content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

Comment: Can you upload a sample json file to Dropbox/Drive so we can see it?

Comment: i've updated question with where i place the content-type and the json files content. it still not working